# Showing that $Sf$ (Uniform Limit of Fourier Series) is Periodic and Continuous

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $\mathbb{T} = [-\pi, \pi]$. From a book on Fourier Analysis:

> [image]

A proof of this is given (using the Weierstrauss M-test), for which I have no qualms. However, afterwards the author states without proof that:

> [image]
>   [image]

**Question:** How do we know that $Sf$ will be (i) periodic and (ii) continuous on $\mathbb{T}$?

My best guess for (ii) is the Uniform Limit Theorem applied to the uniform limit of the partial sums:

$$
\sum_{|n| < N} \hat{f}(n)e^{in\theta}
$$

Is this correct, and if so what about (i)?

Comment: The Weierstrass M-test?

Answer (score 0):

The exponential term has an absolute value of one, meaning that if the sum of $\hat f(n)$ is convergent, than the sum is convergent. Periodicity can be attributed to the complex exponential. For the given interval with range 2$\pi$, it can be shown that the function is periodic by plugging in $-\pi$ and recognizing that has the same effect as plugging in $(2n+1)\pi$. A non-rigorous method to show continuity would be to see if $\lim_{h\to 0+}f(\theta+h)= \lim_{h\to 0-}f(\theta+h)$.

Comment: Continuity follows from uniform convergence.